# 500 error without any error log entry

Tags: 8, debugging

Migrated a Drupal 8 site to another server running apache2 PHP 5.5.9 (should be supported). Apache returns 500 when index.php requested, but no errors are logged anywhere. I tested by forcing an intentional PHP error in index.php and the log contains PHP errors.

I also excluded database connection problems. Taking settings.php out redirects me correctly to /core/install.php and no error is thrown.

Comment: sounds like a folder/file permission problem ... can you see /robots.txt ?

Comment: Yes, can http request /robots.txt

Comment: Than check that your server can handle php properly and file and folder permissions or check the apache and or error logs (perhaps somewhere in /var/log ?)

Comment: As mentioned above, enforcing a PHP error works, error log is written correctly. A standalone test PHP scripts in same directory a works.

Comment: It's probably not a PHP error then. Remove .htaccess and verify you can/can't access /index.php

Comment: Could be your database username/password/host are incorrect in settings.php, that can produce a 500

Comment: @LeighMason But that would leave a standard PHP exception report in the logs

Comment: .htaccess renamed, requested index.php, 500, no error logs written anywhere.

Comment: Really hard to tell without knowing the actual error. Is the server setup properly to log?

Comment: I guess so as enforcing a php error in index.php is logged correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If domain name is changed for new server, you need to clean cache entries. Try using truncate commands for cache tables and confirm back.
You need to have database backup before cleaning tables as well.

Comment: all cache tables manually truncated, including sessions table. Still same 500

Comment: Try with one more alternate server using another php version such as 7. it may seems to not working due to any custom function which may be deprecated.

Comment: You can also use it on local xampp or wamp latest version and check apache log for new server if issue persist.